# Getting Data back from friestore and save it to a class

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this firestore cloud

[image: Press here please]

it consists of 10 elements ordered from 0 to 9 , now i'm trying to get each element of it and save it to a class which i made that consists of email and wealth data types [Here is an image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ftpx.png) , But its not really working out well for me , can someone help me of how can i retrieve it and save it to an object so i can modify it and send it back to firebase as app needs ? 
What i tried :

```
 docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();

                Map <String , Top10Users> try1 = new HashMap<String ,Top10Users>();
                Map <String , Top10Users> top10counter = new HashMap<String ,Top10Users>();
                try1 = (HashMap) doc.getData();
              Top10Users user1 = try1.get("0");
```

And here is the docRef

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
docRef = db.collection("TOP10").document("top10");
```

But it gives me an error saying :

> Can't cast Map to Top10Users

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: edited and added what i've tried

Comment: Please add the code as text and as a picture.

Comment: Edited it now ..